# Linux Ubuntu Password reset

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, root, password-recovery

I used the passwd >username< on Ubuntu, and it gave me a list of options. How do I get past them? If I try using the options, it won't let me. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To change the user password in Ubuntu from the terminal type:

```
sudo passwd your-username
```

where for `your-username` substitute your username. You will see the following prompt;

```
[sudo] password for your-username
```

Authenticate with your password and you will see the following prompt:

```
Enter new UNIX password:
```

Type your new password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you will be prompted to type your new password again to verify that your new password has been typed correctly both times.

Comment: worked for me :)